# Is $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ or ${\mathbb{Z}_2}^n$ correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

There is not much more to the question than the subject really.

When defining a vector $x$ to be a vector with $n$ elements from the set $\{0,1\}$, is it correct to say $x \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$ or $x \in {\mathbb{Z}_2}^n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either is correct, but I more commonly see $\mathbb Z_2^n$.

Comment: I agree with this sentiment. It's a lot cleaner looking and easier in $\rm\LaTeX$ than putting parens in.

Comment: @Matt How you can say it is correct for non prime $p$

Comment: @MANI what does it matter if it is not prime?

Comment: I thinkIf $n$ is not prime then $\mathbb{Z}_n^2$ does not forms a vector space

Comment: @MANI We're not talking about $\mathbb Z_n^2$, but rather $\mathbb Z_2^n$.

Comment: While the reader might confuse ${\Bbb Z_2}^n$ with $\Bbb Z_{2^n}$, it is the writer (or the typist) who might confuse $\Bbb Z_{2^n}$ with $\Bbb Z_2^n$... :-)